# Why is Spark making certain columns of a CSV file to nulls when there is data in those columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a json file, convert it to CSV in PySpark as below.

```
df = spark.read.json(inputdir')
```

I have the below schema which I am imposing on my dataframe.

```
mechanic_schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("some_other_column", StringType(), True),
    StructField("url", StringType(), True),
    StructField("image", StringType(), True),
    StructField("startTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("recipeYield", StringType(), True),
    StructField("datePublished", StringType(), True),
    StructField("endTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("description", StringType(), True)
])
```

I am saving the dataframe: `df` in an output directory as below.

```
df.select(mechanic_schema.names).write.format('csv').option("header","true").save(''/Users/bobby/Desktop/output/', header='true')
```

This is how the output looks like:

```
df.show()
```

[image]

Now in another script, I am reading the same csv file that I saved in output path of `df` as below:

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', True).load('/Users/bobby/Desktop/output/')
df.show()
```

But strangely, the output contains so many columns as `null`s which looks like this:
[image]

So I checked my output CSV file and the data looks exactly fine there.
[image]

I have never come across this phenomenon until now and don't understand what did I do wrong here.
Could anyone let me know what is causing this issue and how can fix this problem ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have full picture here, but one of my guess is, your original dataframe **actually** have null data like that, only you **don't see** it because `show` display only 20 rows. Now, when you save it all to CSV, Spark created multiple files and records are unordered. Then, when you read from CSV, `show` picks up the "first" 20 rows, which possibly all null first, that's why you have an impression that Spark doesn't write properly

Comment: My suggestion is, pick a column, try to count `null` values on it and compare it against the csv read, to see if both data are exactly the same

Comment: It looks like you have either multiline or not properly quoted item in the csv.  Looking at the "I have a good, ...", in the `endTime` column.  That _sounds_ like it should be in `description`.  Could you paste the plain csv text that you outputted?  My wild guess is `.option('multiLine', 'true')` will  help as I am looking at the excel file, how it is rendered there.

Comment: @pltc I don't have any null values in the dataframe. All the columns are filled with values

Comment: @Emma yes, there are multiline strings in the data and I am going to try it and post the results back.

Comment: @Emma Even the multiline option is not working.

Comment: Do you add to the read?  could you update your question with the multiline code?  Also could you add a sample line of outputted csv in plain text?